# Error SQLCODE=-443, SQLSTATE=38553 after applying fix pack 8 to DB2 v10.5

Tags: db2, db2-luw

We have an utility which retrieves some data from DB2 (v 10.5 for AIX) database. After we had applied Fix Pack 8 to database (client and JDBC driver had been also updated) this utility didn’t work. There was the following error in log:

```
13:09:48,270 [INFO  ] SMU  {SCSExecute.Execute.java}  13:09:48,258 [ERROR ] org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.DatabaseFileSystem  failed to initialize file system
13:09:48,277 [INFO  ] SMU  {SCSExecute.Execute.java}  com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-443, SQLSTATE=38553, SQLERRMC=SYSIBM.SQLTABLES;TABLES;SYSIBM:CLI:-514, DRIVER=3.69.66
```

As recommended here (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21369762) for similar cases we executed the following commands in DB2:

```
db2 connect to <databasename> 
db2 bind db2schema.bnd blocking all grant public sqlerror continue 
db2 terminate
```

But it didn’t solve the issues.

What could we forget to do?
How could we check that bind command executed properly?
How could we try to solve the issue or reveal its root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not having replied! We have solved the problem by execution of the following actions:

1) Execute commands in DB2:

```
db2 terminate 
db2 CONNECT TO dbname user USERID using PASSWORD
db2 BIND path\db2schema.bnd BLOCKING ALL GRANT PUBLIC SQLERROR CONTINUE 
db2 BIND path\@db2ubind.lst BLOCKING ALL GRANT PUBLIC ACTION ADD 
db2 BIND path\@db2cli.lst BLOCKING ALL GRANT PUBLIC ACTION ADD 
db2 terminate
```

2) (VERY IMPORTANT!!!) Restart DB instance.

Answer (score 1):

> What could we forget to do?

As documented in the DB2 fixpack readme, after you install on the server, `db2schema.bnd` needs to be bound to existing databases.

> How could we check that bind command executed properly?

If you installed the fix pack on `DB2 database` products that have existing databases, perform the following commands once for each database:

```
db2 terminate 
db2 CONNECT TO dbname user USERID using PASSWORD
db2 BIND path\db2schema.bnd BLOCKING ALL GRANT PUBLIC SQLERROR CONTINUE 
db2 BIND path\@db2ubind.lst BLOCKING ALL GRANT PUBLIC ACTION ADD 
db2 BIND path\@db2cli.lst BLOCKING ALL GRANT PUBLIC ACTION ADD 
db2 terminate
```

where dbname represents the name of a database to which the files should be bound, and where path is the full path name of the directory where the bind files are located, such as INSTHOME\sqllib\bnd where INSTHOME represents the home directory of the DB2 instance. db2ubind.lst and db2cli.lst contain lists of required bind files used by DB2 database products.

> How could we try to solve the issue or reveal its root?

may be the installation of the DB2 fixpack was incomplete.

For further your ref:- [DB2 SQL Error occurs after DB2 patch install](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21615695)

Comment: Thanks for reply. But as I wrote in my message we executed these commands with no results. So, how could we check that db2schema.bnd was actually bound to database?

Comment: @PierreVanStulov, Binding bind files after installing fix packs https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/t0024970.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have successfully completed post-installation tasks as [described in the manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/t0024995.html), specifically, run `db2updv105` and rebind all bind files anew. The error message indicates that the CLI package causes the problem, so you need to at least bind all files in `db2cli.lst`:

```
db2 BIND <path>/@db2cli.lst BLOCKING ALL GRANT PUBLIC
```

Comment: Thanks for usefull instruction to see manual! Step 4 solved our issues :)